# Delete, hide, not display visited links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 1000 links each time I update the page 
I want show only the links that have not been visited and links that have been visited not show or remove.

I want to show only unvisited links, and visited links will not be displayed.

Maybe there is a way to not display visited links by plugin browser, browser configuration, using javascript or php?

I tried with css:

```
.someclass a:visited {display: none;}
```

but does not work, any idea.

Update:

Other option: show up only unvisited links and visited links displayed below ?
is possible ?

Thank.

Comment: show complete code that you've tried

Comment: Is `a: visited` a typo? It should be `a:visited` (without the space).

Comment: @hyubs nope, that would still not work. See my answer for the explanation why. (although indeed it is supposed to be `a:visited`).

Comment: you can only change some properties using :visited, and display is not one of them. color and opacity do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, this is not possible. [The CSS `:visited` selector is heavily protected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited#privacy_restrictions), because giving full access to it would make it possible for others to go through your history, by checking which sites you have visited already.

The only things you can do to visited links is the things that wouldn't change the space they take up in the document, but only change its appearance. You could mark the link as visited by coloring it purple, or making it lighter. Then the user will have to decide what to do with that.

Comment: Fascinating. I wasn't aware of this vector to compromise privacy.

Comment: Didn't know that there was a restriction to `:visited`. Learned something new today.

Comment: For the record, here are [some more details](http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy) and how Mozilla decides to [handle it](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/comment-page-1/)

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Joeytje50's answer that `:visited` is a bust, the solution that I can think of is storing visited page's URL in [HTML5 Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). Then check the local storage for URLs that you need to hide.

You can also store it in cookies but you have more space to work with if you use local storage.

NOTE: Check the browser support of local storage [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)